# Failed to compile Try to add two numbers using angular

Tags: angular

i am a beginner of angular.i want to add two number to calculate total.when i tried to do it i got the error was Failed to compile.what i tried so far i attached below.

**table.component.html**

```
<form>
         
          <label >Num 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num1" [(ngModel)]="num1" name="num1"  placeholder="Enter email">
          
      

          <label >Num 2</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num2" [(ngModel)]="num2" name="num2"  placeholder="Enter email">
         
    

         <label>{{ parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2)  }}</label>

          <button (click)="myClickFunction" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
        </form>
```

**table.component.js**

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  num1 : number = 0;
  num2 : number= 0;
```

Comment: Please share the error message.

Comment: this is error message i got it at console  Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode.

Comment: It is not error. Just information.

Comment: i added complete error above

Comment: now my solved the error my problem is when enter two number it is not calculating and display the total

Comment: @raduba, I suggest not use "parseFloat", you can use a simple `+` to convert a string to number:`{{ (+num1) + (+num2)  }}`. BTW, Iyou has an error is in your `(click)`, should be: `(click)="myClickFunction()"` -see the final parenthesis-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>         
    <label >Num 1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num1" [(ngModel)]="num1" name="num1"  placeholder="Enter email">
    
    <label >Num 2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num2" [(ngModel)]="num2" name="num2"  placeholder="Enter email">
    
    <label>{{ (+num1) + (+num2)  }}</label> // Replace parseFloat with `+`

    <button (click)="myClickFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button> // fill the missing `()`
</form>
```

You can see live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lmqpqg?file=src/app/app.component.html).

*PS: In Angular 12, to avoid `NaN` as result, you can also do:

`<label>{{ (+num1 ?? 0) + (+num2 ?? 0)  }}</label>`

In previous versions you could write it like this:

`<label>{{ (+num1 ? +num1 : 0) + (+num2 ? +num2 : 0)  }}</label>`
*

Comment: thanks it works succesfully i need when click the button total need to display

Comment: Nice @raduba! If it helped, you can vote up and/or mark as accepted answer

Comment: thanks i done it. please help when click the button total need to display

Comment: I don't understand your problem, do you want the label to be visible only when button has been clicked?

Comment: sir i need to enter two number on the input field and click the button total displayed the alert msg

Comment: ```onClick() { alert((+this.num1 ? +this.num1 : 0) + (+this.num2 ? +this.num2 : 0)); } ```

Comment: <button onClick({ alert((+this.num1 ? +this.num1 : 0) + (+this.num2 ? +this.num2 : 0)); }) type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>  i tried button not shown up

Comment: @raduba, I strongly advise you to read some JS basics first...